# Mackey coset decomposition formula

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, finite-groups, homogeneous-spaces, equivariant-cohomology

I have a question about following argument I found
in [these notes](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/WebbMF.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiiu9Lu7d6AAxVg_rsIHU-KCSEQFnoECBAQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1OZ96p6a5V9Y-wW04DRo45) on Mackey functors:

> **(2.1) LEMMA.** (page 6) Let $G$ be a finite group and $J$ any subgroup. Whenever $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $J$, there is a pullback diagram of $G$-sets

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Omega  @>{}  >> G/K \\
@VVV  @VVV  \\
G/H @>{}>> G/J
\end{CD}
$$

where we have Mackey double coset decomposition $\Omega= \coprod_{x \in [H\backslash J/K]}G/(H \cap x^{-1}Kx)$

The proof shows by hand for the special case $G=J$ that the pullback in

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
J/K \times J/H  @>{}  >> J/K \\
@VVV  @VVV  \\
J/H @>{}>> J/J = \{*\}
\end{CD}
$$

is given by decomposition $J/K \times J/H= \coprod_{x \in [H\backslash J/K]}J/(H \cap x^{-1}Kx)$ and then claims then claims that the result follows from application of the usual induction functor $\text{Ind}^G _J: (J-\text{Set}) \to  (G-\text{Set})$ sending a $J$-set $S$ to $G$-set $G \times_J S$.

**Question:** Why this functor preserves *limits* (eg a pullback as in this case). It is well known that the induction functor  $\text{Ind}^G _J$ is *left-adjoint* to usual restriction functor $\text{Res}^J _G$, and therefore definitely preserves colimits. But the pullback in the question is a limit, so I not understand why the induction functor applied to $J/K \times J/H$
from the special case preserves the limit/ pullback property.

A remark: I found googling this problem several alternative proofs of the claimed decomposition formula, but the objection of this question is really to understand why *this* argument given by Webb in the linked notes works, ie why in this situation the induction functor commutes with the pullback.

Comment: I believe for finite groups induction is isomorphic to coinduction and so it is also a right adjoint.  Coinduction woild look at J-equivariant maps from G->X.   If [G:J] is finite, you can choose coset reps and set up an isomorphism with Gx_J X.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: Following your approach, say we have choosen some representing elements of the cosets $G/J$. How can we then explicitly build up from this an iso   from $\operatorname{Hom}_J(G, X)$ to $G \times_J X$ in explicit terms?

Comment: I'm used to these being isomorphic for modules.  At the level of sets it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: that's the point.  for $K[G]$ modules as you said the story works perfectly ( eg here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3592269) but I don't know (even doubt that it's possible) how to "translate" the identifications used there to G-sets...

Comment: The cardinalities don't match up

Comment: I think the correct argument is G is a free J-set.  I believe this means it preserves nonempty finite  limits when you tensor with it

Comment: There is a general result if M is a monoid and X is a right M-set such that each connect component of the category of elements is filtering then tensoring with X preserves pull backs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The induction functor preserves all *(weakly) connected* limits (note that this covers pullbacks, but not products - and of course, because it doesn't preserve the terminal object, it couldn't do both !).

There is a more general way to argue, but in this case you can say as follows (there is also probably a more concrete one) : one can check on underlying objects whether this preserves a given limit diagram. But forgetting the $G$-structure on $Ind_J^G$ is equivalent to forgetting the $J$-structure and taking a $G/J$-indexed constant coproduct. Thus it suffices to check that coproducts on the category of sets commute with weakly connected limits.

To prove this, note that for a given set $I$ (the indexing set), the equivalence $Set^I \simeq Set_{/I}$ intertwines the "coproduct" functor and the forgetful functor.

But now it is a general fact that if $C$ has $K$-shaped limits, and $K$ is weakly connected, then the forgetful functor $C_{/x} \to C$ preserves $K$-shaped limits.

Comment: just clarify: by "coproduct functor" you mean the dual of this thing https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Product_Functor

Comment: also, what do you mean by " weakly" connected limit? so far I see, a limit is connected if the underlying diagram is connected as graph, but what means "weakly" here?

Comment: Yes, I mean the dual of that, or that but with possibly more variables. And I mean that the underlying *undirected* graph is connected - hence, the weakly.